# git checkout (Windows 10/mingw64) errors with "no such file or directory"

Tags: windows, git

Trying to develop in Windows 10 with a project that was developed on Linux.  Code is stored in GitLab, and I'm seeing the following error with multiple repositories.  Using git version 2.15.1.windows.2

Here's an example:

```
→ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 5, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Total 5 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (5/5), done.
From myurl:project/master
   c23fc916..6dd18de8  master     -> origin/master
error: unable to create file test/template/PRN.template: No such file or directory
Updating c23fc916..6dd18de8
```

Definitely not the long path (Longer file names were checked out, and I've moved the directory to shorten the total length):

```
→ git config --system -l
...
core.longpaths=true
```

Further, it wrote 3 other files in that directory before erroring out:

```
→ ls -1 test/template/
'Complex Testing Scenario.template'
create_from_template.py
Scheduled.template
```

If I use GIT_TRACE, I see:

```
→ GIT_TRACE=1 git pull
18:16:13.337044 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'pull'
18:16:13.342045 run-command.c:626       trace: run_command: 'fetch' '--update-head-ok'
18:16:13.355048 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'fetch' '--update-head-ok'
18:16:13.361063 run-command.c:626       trace: run_command: 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\PLINK.EXE' 'git@xxxxxxx' 'git-upload-pack '\''xxxxxxx/master.git'\'''
18:16:19.820957 run-command.c:626       trace: run_command: 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all' '--quiet'
18:16:19.882937 run-command.c:626       trace: run_command: 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all' '--quiet'
18:16:19.897933 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all' '--quiet'
18:16:19.976095 run-command.c:1452      run_processes_parallel: preparing to run up to 1 tasks
18:16:19.976095 run-command.c:1484      run_processes_parallel: done
18:16:19.976095 run-command.c:626       trace: run_command: 'gc' '--auto'
18:16:19.988095 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'gc' '--auto'
18:16:19.999065 run-command.c:626       trace: run_command: 'merge' 'FETCH_HEAD'
18:16:20.013068 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'merge' 'FETCH_HEAD'
error: unable to create file test/template/PRN.template: No such file or directory
Updating c23fc916..6dd18de8
```

(BTW, this fails on both Git for Windows, TortoiseGit, and when trying to clone via IntelliJ)

However, if I fire up WSL/Ubuntu and check it out into my home directory (so in my NTFS partition), it works fine:

```
 2018-01-17 19:49:25   DESKTOP-GPVE514 in /mnt/c/Users/mcrow/Programming
○ → git clone --branch master git@xxxxxxxxx/master.git
Cloning into 'master'...
remote: Counting objects: 24462, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (108/108), done.
remote: Total 24462 (delta 115), reused 87 (delta 68)
Receiving objects: 100% (24462/24462), 277.43 MiB | 840.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (17596/17596), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Checking out files: 100% (2521/2521), done.
```

Best I can figure, it's definitely something with Git for Windows writing files, but I can't figure out what.

Here's more info:  After checking out via WSL/Ubuntu, I went to that directory and did a `git status`.  That shows:

```
→ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    test/template/PRN.template

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

However, that file is there:

```
→ ls -1 test/template/
total 14
'Complex Testing Scenario.template'
create_from_template.py
PRN.template
Scheduled.template
```

But, from Windows, it's still an issue:

```
→ git reset --hard HEAD
error: unable to create file test/template/PRN.template: No such file or directory
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this work on Ubuntu, but not on Windows, double-check the case (upercase/lowercase) of the path (parent folders) or of the file itself.

Windows would not be able to checkout a file with a path or name similar to another one, with a different case.

Comment: I thought this might be the case, but I attempted to fix it on the linux side (renaming the file).  I had to finally rename the file on the windows side to fully resolve it